# Drupal will not preview on action "Blue wheel spins with no action"

Tags: css, image, drupal, preview

For some odd reason when I create content that has a image field, after upload the "blue progress wheel" spins but no preview of image appears. This was a bump in the road, but I just hit save every time I uploaded a image and edited content and the image showed.

Screen show of progress wheel but no image loading:[image]

HOWEVER, now if I go to Views and show images from images fields, they will not show in view block preview. Screenshot:[image]

Also this issues of not seeing anything load after I edit my Content Type Displays:

[image]

I'm using Drupal 7.28 core. Is there a way to see why this is happening (error log?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if this is happening due to a PHP error, you will get the log at "Administrator=>Reports=>Recent log messages".

```
/admin/reports/dblog
```

Comment: Well I figured out this was caused by the SimpleMenu module I had installed. Once I disabled it, everything worked great. However I really need SuperMenu Module.